# What are the ways to get the data from XML file using C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to get the data from XML File using C# and i need to assign this data to a dto. Here i need to consider performance also when getting the data from xml file. I already used xml deserialization to get the data from xml file but it is taking lot of time to get the data from large xml files. Please suggest me a solution considering performance using C#.

Comment: Please see the following link. It tests 3 ways of reading xml, XmlDocument, LINQ to XML and XmlReader: https://www.altamiracorp.com/blog/employee-posts/performance-linq-to-sql-vs

Answer (score 0):

If your XML file is too huge then you can use the [XMLReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx). Also you can look into the [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) option.

Example:

```
<Branch>
    <Node>
        <MyNode>
            <SubNode code=\"0\">
                My message
            </SubNode>
        </MyNode>
    </Node>
</Branch>
```

Using LINQ to XML

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var subnode = from x in doc.Descendants("SubNode")
             select new
             {
                code = x.Attribute("code").Value,
                msg = x.Value.Trim()
             };

foreach (var e in subnode)
{

}
```